# SQL - Very slow retrieval of records

Tags: sql

I have a `[User]` table which has 35k records. I also have another table `[UserNote]`, which has about 1M records.

When I do a `LEFT JOIN` with the `User` and `UserNote` tables, it takes a long time to run a query.

I tried adding index to the tables but no luck!

Is there any ways to overcome this issue?

Query:

```
SELECT u.Name, un.Notes 
FROM [User] u
LEFT JOIN [UserNote] un ON un.UserID = u.UserID
ORDER BY u.Name
```

Thanks

Comment: post your query

Comment: Added, please check the edited question.

Comment: could you add execution plan as well. In first instance I assume UserId is INT. Did you try to add INDEX to the User.name?

Comment: which columns you have added as index on?

Comment: I added INDEX to the notes column. UserID having clustered index since it is a primary key column!

Comment: Also i have index on u.Name field

Comment: You might try with clustered index UserNote.UserID. I've had some 40% quicker response time that way.

Comment: Table can have only one ClusteredIndex, UserNote has UserNoteID as clustered index!

Comment: Convert it to nonclustered for the sake of test. Later, if it seems that your query works faster now, see index statistics to determine which one is more important.

Comment: Why have you written a query to return all 1M+ rows? Of course selecting them all and Then ordering them is slow. Why would you ever want to do that to All of the rows? It's like you're missing a WHERE clause to get the rows you're Actually interested in.

Comment: have you tried LEFT HASH JOIN? It would be useful as well if you could include the execution plan in the question as well (if you are using mssql)

Also, how long is it actually? It may also have to be that long depending on the performance of the sql server.

Answer (score 1):

> ORDER BY u.Name

I'm willing to bet this is your culprit.  You're producing a result of 35 million rows, and then you have to sort it on a column outside the join criteria.  You don't say what a "long time" is, but I bet if you remove the `order by`, or restrict the output with a WHERE clause on `u.Name`, it will be much faster.

I assume u.UserID is unique, and un.UserID is not, because each user has many notes, else the notes would be in the user table.  I assume un.UserID is the first column in some unique index on that table, perhaps implicitly defined by the table.  If not, it probably should be.

You *might* have better luck with an inner join.  But that advice, along with any speculation on how to formulate your query, depends on your implementation.

Comment: Appropriate indexes would help. Acknowledging the indexes ability to fulfil both the sort and the join.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Non Clustered index in UserNote table for UserID and include column Notes something like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UserId_Notes  
ON UserNotes (UserId)  
INCLUDE (Notes);
```

This is called as covering index, in this case, when you do a join and ask for notes, you query don't need to do a look up on the base table (User Notes), it have all the needed columns in non-clusetered index itself.

You can also think about adding UserId, Notes in the non-clustered index. But I would not suggest that. Please comment if it's not clear.

Comment: Also adding an index on `User(Name, UserID)` may be more beneficial due to the OP sorting the output by Name.

Comment: Yeah agree, but that's in the users table, but this case definitely need the above index i specified. And I prefer writing relational queries (ORDER / SORT should be handled by the front end / application which displays the data) ,

Comment: I disagree about sorting be application specific. Window / analytic functions, for example, depend on it. Also, in this case, if you assert the sorting shouldn't be done here, and it's likely that's the most expensive part of the query, you should state that in the answer.